# Getting null for some of the columns in MySQL, Laravel, Translation

Tags: mysql, laravel

My models are as follows:

Faq:

```
class Faq extends Model
{
    use Translatable;

    public $translatedAttributes = ['question', 'answer'];

    public function faqtranslations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(FaqTranslation::class);
    }
}
```

and FaqTranslation:

```
class FaqTranslation extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['question', 'answer'];
}
```

And here is my `show` method from FaqController:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $faq = Faq::find($id);

    $faq_translations = Faq::join('faq_translations as t', 't.faq_id', '=', 'faqs.id')
        ->where('t.faq_id', $id)
        ->select('t.locale','t.question','t.answer')
        ->get();

    return view('dashboard.faqs.show', compact('faq_translations'));
}
```

Following are the results on the view page:

- `{{$faq_translations}}` correctly displays `[{"locale":"lv","question":"lv-q","answer":"lv-a"},{"locale":"ru","question":"ru-q","answer":"ru-a"},{"locale":"en","question":"en-q","answer":"en-a"}]`
- `{{$faq_translations[0]->locale}}` correctly displays `lv`
- `{{$faq_translations[0]->question}}` incorrectly displays `null` (should show `lv-q`)

The same is true for other members of the array.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your code this way.

```
public function show(Faq $faq)
{
    $faq_translations = $faq->faqtranslations()->get();

    return view('dashboard.faqs.show', compact('faq_translations'));
}
```

Make sure you have same `wildcard` name i.e. `faq` in route as well as controller

```
Route::get('faqs/{faq}', 'FaqsController@show');
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It has worked. I am new to MySQl, i have a question - Why I have to use get() method at the end?

Comment: The `get` method returns an `Illuminate\Support\Collection` containing the results where each result is an instance of the `PHP StdClass` object. You may access each column's value by accessing the column as a property of the object:

Comment: As expalined here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#introduction If it solves your problem. Vote up the answer. :)